# -fshort-wchar and std::wstring - segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libstdc++

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and gcc 7.5.0. I have a library which is compiled with -fshort-wchar. I have noticed that using `std::wstring` in the library  may leads to the segmentation fault. I have found a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286568/implication-of-using-fshort-wchar). There is an explanation:

> -fshort-wchar is not usable if you want to interact with any part of the standard library or third-party library code using the correct (32-bit) definition of wchar_t.

I understand that I can't use `std::wstring` when a library is compiled with `-fshort-wchar` but what with the other standard library content ? Why I can't interact with any part of the standard library, for example std::vector ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Why I can't interact with any part of..." ? Did you try it? As long as no `wchar_t`s are passed around it should be fine

Comment: Right, I have misunderstood that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-fshort-wchar          sets the size of wchar_t to 2 bytes
```

Now think about what will happen if you use a part of the standard library that is **not** header only. A big part of the standard library is compiled into a library that you link with (`libstdc++` / `libc++`). When that was compiled `-fshort-wchar` was not used and the size of the `wchar_t` is therefore 4 bytes in the library.

Comment: Ted always with the thoughtful explanations

Comment: @SombreroChicken Thanks! I'm not sure I explained it better than what OP already linked to though. I didn't read that link before typing. A bit trigger-happy perhaps. :-)